# Python sorting by the max of the first element, then the min of the second element

Tags: python, sorting

I was working on a geometry project in python and I came across an intriguing problem. Assume I have a list of Cartesian coordinates like this:

`[[1, 0], [3, 0], [2, 1], [3.5, 2], [4, 3], [6, 1], [6.5, 0], [10, 2], [10, 5], [9, 3.5], [7, 3], [9, 7], [7, 8], [5, 7], [4, 5], [2, 8], [1, 7], [0, 5], [1, 3], [0, 2]]`

What would be the best way to sort this list by descending y-value THEN increasing x-value if two coordinates exist with the same y-value? The output should be:

`[[2, 8], [7, 8], [1, 7], [5, 7], [9, 7], [0, 5], [4, 5], [10, 5], [9, 3.5], [1, 3], [4, 3], [7, 3], [0, 2], [3.5, 2], [10, 2], [2, 1], [6, 1], [1, 0], [3, 0], [6.5, 0]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply a key function to [`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) to determine what value each item in your list should be mapped to for sorting. In your case, you can use a tuple of the negative Y-coordinate, and the X-coordinate to get your desired result:

```
>>> coordinates = [[1, 0], [3, 0], [2, 1], [3.5, 2], [4, 3], [6, 1], [6.5, 0], [10, 2], [10, 5], [9, 3.5], [7, 3], [9, 7], [7, 8], [5, 7], [4, 5], [2, 8], [1, 7], [0, 5], [1, 3], [0, 2]]
>>> coordinates.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
>>> coordinates
[[2, 8], [7, 8], [1, 7], [5, 7], [9, 7], [0, 5], [4, 5], [10, 5], [9, 3.5], [1, 3], [4, 3], [7, 3], [0, 2], [3.5, 2], [10, 2], [2, 1], [6, 1], [1, 0], [3, 0], [6.5, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Poke's answer is the right answer in most cases.

Just in case you are doing this on Python prior to Python 2.4 or if the comparison function is really expensive, you can use Decorate-Sort-Undecorate (DSU or the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform))

```
>>> coord = [[1, 0], [3, 0], [2, 1], [3.5, 2], [4, 3], [6, 1], [6.5, 0], [10, 2], [10, 5], [
9, 3.5], [7, 3], [9, 7], [7, 8], [5, 7], [4, 5], [2, 8], [1, 7], [0, 5], [1, 3], [0, 2]]
>>> decorated=[[(-y,x),x,y] for x,y in coord]
>>> [[x,y] for t,x,y in sorted(decorated)]
[[2, 8], [7, 8], [1, 7], [5, 7], [9, 7], [0, 5], [4, 5], [10, 5], [9, 3.5], [1, 3], [4, 3], [7, 3], [0, 2], [3.5, 2], [10, 2], [2, 1], [6, 1], [1, 0], [3, 0], [6.5, 0]]
```

Or:

```
>>> [[x,y] for t,x,y in sorted([[(-y,x),x,y] for x,y in coord])]
[[2, 8], [7, 8], [1, 7], [5, 7], [9, 7], [0, 5], [4, 5], [10, 5], [9, 3.5], [1, 3], [4, 3], [7, 3], [0, 2], [3.5, 2], [10, 2], [2, 1], [6, 1], [1, 0], [3, 0], [6.5, 0]]
```

These techniques (and more) are in the Python [sorting HowTo](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Comment: *“Python prior to Python 2.4”* – I just hope that’s nowhere the case…

Comment: +1 for the tencity of presenting a pre-python 2.4 solution =)

Comment: Huh, I've never heard of DSU sorting, thats a neat little method! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @poke: Lots of people don't update their Python for 10, 11 years! ;-)

Comment: Support for Python 2.4 ended in 2008 though, so I’m not sure why I should give them support for their problems if they still use it :P

Comment: Mostly I just think it is a useful method for languages that do NOT have key functions (Perl, Lisp, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Using `sorted` and specifying the sorting criterion with a `lambda` function using a tuple:

```
>>> coord = [[1, 0], [3, 0], [2, 1], [3.5, 2], [4, 3], [6, 1], [6.5, 0], [10, 2], [10, 5], [9, 3.5], [7, 3], [9, 7], [7, 8], [5, 7], [4, 5], [2, 8], [1, 7], [0, 5], [1, 3], [0, 2]]
>>> sorted(coord, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[[2, 8], [7, 8], [1, 7], [5, 7], [9, 7], [0, 5], [4, 5], [10, 5], [9, 3.5], [1, 3], [4, 3], [7, 3], [0, 2], [3.5, 2], [10, 2], [2, 1], [6, 1], [1, 0], [3, 0], [6.5, 0]]
```

The order in the lambda function tuple defines the order by which the criterion are considered.

> x[1] : sort by second element in ascending order
>
> -x[1] : sort by second element in descending order
>
> x[0] : sort by first element in ascending order

Comment: How is this different than @poke's answer?

Comment: `sorted(x)` , `x.sort()` hmmmm, i wonder. i'm just slow in typing... hahahaa

Comment: @dawg, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort-python