# list sort error using key parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to sort `todo` as per the order in `priority`

```
>>> todo
['see doctor', 'do assignment', 'pay rent', 'check bank account', 'clean room']

>>> priority
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]

>>> todo.sort(key=lambda x: priority[todo.index(x)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
ValueError: 'see doctor' is not in list
```

Why am I getting this error when trying to sort `todo` like this ?

Works with `sorted` though:

```
>>> sorted(todo, key=lambda x: priority[todo.index(x)])
['pay rent', 'check bank account', 'see doctor', 'do assignment', 'clean room']
```

Why does it work with `sorted` but not with `sort`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting list based on values from another list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Comment: @BhargavRao Yes and no: the solution is the same, and essentially the problem as well. The duplicate question however, despite multiple answers, does not explain *why* the OP gets the error they get.

Comment: @Evert Exactly. I understand how to sort based on key. My question here is why am I getting the error in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can simply [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the 2 list and then sort it on the basis of `priority` by using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
>>> todo = ['see doctor', 'do assignment', 'pay rent', 'check bank account', 'clean room']
>>> priority = [3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
>>> [y for (x,y) in sorted(zip(priority, todo))]
['pay rent', 'check bank account', 'see doctor', 'do assignment', 'clean room']
```

**EDIT:** The reason as to why you are getting the error `ValueError: 'see doctor' is not in list` is because there is a difference between using [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and the built-in function [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

> `sorted()` returns a **new** sorted list, leaving the original list unaffected. `list.sort()` sorts the list **in-place**, mutating the list indices.

You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22442440/2932244) for more clarification regarding the difference.

If you refer the [source code for `list.sort()`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c) (the `listsort()` function), you'll notice a comment within the function that says -

> The list is temporarily made empty, so that mutations performed by comparison functions can't affect the slice of memory we're sorting.

Hence, when the lambda function executes, it tries to find the index of `'see doctor'` in the list (from `todo.index(x)`). But since the list is empty, it returns the `ValueError: 'see doctor' is not in list`.

This error is not thrown for `sorted()` because it initializes a new empty list and then appends the strings into the newly created list without modify the given list (i.e. `todo`).

Source code for [`list.sort()`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c) and [`sorted()`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/bltinmodule.c).

Comment: This is not the answer to the question that I have. Please read it again.

Comment: @abc - I've edited the answer. Hope this helps solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Jason has given you the (better) solution (or go numpy and use numpy array indexing; even simpler).

As to *why* you get that error: you're sorting `todo` *in-place* in your first code; at the same time, you ask for `todo`, thus you're asking for a list that's being altered in-place. That's not a good idea.
`sorted()` works, because a copy of `todo` is made first, and that copy is sorted, so `.index()` is still called on the original `todo`.

---

With numpy:

```
>>> todo = np.array(todo)
>>> priority = np.array(priority) - 1  # Python is 0-based
>>> todo[priority]
array(['pay rent', 'check bank account', 'see doctor', 'do assignment',
   'clean room'], dtype='|S18')
>>> print(todo[priority])
['pay rent' 'check bank account' 'see doctor' 'do assignment' 'clean room']
```