# Error with negative numbers in list. Wrong output.

Tags: python, list, set

```
N=int(raw_input())
A=raw_input()
a_list=A.split()
for i in xrange (len(a_list)):
    a_list[i]=int(a_list[i])
s=list(set(a_list))
sorted(s)
print s
```

When I put N=5 and put all positive values, I get the list s in increasing order, but when I put N=5 and put negative values, It does not give me a list in increasing order. Why ?

Comment: `sorted(s)` builds a sorted list that you completely ignore and throw away. It doesn't affect `s` at all.

Comment: You should use `s.sort()` instead.

Comment: Used s.sort()
It works!!

Comment: @SaranshArora, I hope my answer and explanation is what you are looking for !

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you are using `sorted`, sorted() returns a new sorted list, leaving the original list unaffected

`sort()` sorts the list in-place, mutating the list indices, and returns None

We cam use sorted on any itterable, list, dict, string, tupple.

Hence, use `sorted(),` when you want a sorted object back and `sort()` when u want to mutate the list.

As compare with `sorted()`, `sort()` is fast as it do not copy.

Read complete here : [What is the difference between `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort-python)

**SOLUTION :**

```
    N=int(raw_input())
    A=raw_input()
    a_list=A.split()
    for i in xrange (len(a_list)):
        a_list[i]=int(a_list[i])
    s=list(set(a_list))
    s.sort()
    print(s)
```

Comment: Your explanation is completely wrong. `sorted` isn't a method of any class at all, and what class these functions or methods are or aren't attached to doesn't dictate whether they operate in-place.

Comment: Any description about the answer and what's wrong in the question ❓