# Given a list L of video names and their watch rates, write a function that will return the videos with the top 10 watch rates

Tags: python, python-3.x

Video names may appear more than once.
Example:
L = [('abc',10),('def',15),('ghi',10),('abc', 12), ...,('xyz',100)]
The function should return ['xyz','abc',...,'def','ghi']

Here is what I have so far (which doesn't work and I can't seem to fix it no matter what I try):

```
def ranked_games(L):
    sorted_list = [x for x in L.items()]
    sorted_list.sort(key = lambda x:x[1]) #sort by value
    sorted_list.reverse()
    print("Sorted by Value Descending",sorted_list)
```

I would appreciate any insight on either a better way to approach this or if you know what's wrong with my code... thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Does this accomplish what you're after?

```
L = [('abc',10),('def',15),('ghi',10),('abc', 12),('xyz',100)]
print("Sorted by Value Descending",[i[0] for i in sorted(L, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)][:10])
```

Comment: You can try with `reverse` inside `sorted`: `sorted(L, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)[:10]`

Comment: I would guess that his intent was to copy the list, so it the original list wouldn't be sorted in place.

Comment: @TimJohns yes, perhaps that was *her* intent :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I didn't check the OP's name first.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
L = [('abc',10),('def',15),('ghi',10),('abc', 12),('xyz',100)]

def ranked_games(L):
    sorted_list = sorted(L,key = lambda x:x[1],reverse=True) #sort by value
    print("Sorted by Value Descending",[i[0] for i in sorted_list]) 

ranked_games(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

For fixing the code above, you can simply try following:

```
def ranked_games(L):
    L.sort(key = lambda x:x[1], reverse=True) #sort by value
    print("Sorted by Value Descending", [i for i, _ in L[:10]]) # [:10] for slicing 10 sorted values

# calling the function
my_list = [('abc',10),('def',15),('ghi',10),('abc', 12),('xyz',100)]
ranked_games(my_list)
print('Original List: ', my_list)
```

Result:

```
Sorted by Value Descending ['xyz', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'ghi']
Original List:  [('xyz', 100), ('def', 15), ('abc', 12), ('abc', 10), ('ghi', 10)]
```

Note that the original list is also sorted since `.sort` method of list is called. If you do not want the original list to be sorted then you may want to call `sorted` function and pass in list as a parameter as below:

```
def ranked_games(L):
    sorted_list = sorted(L, key = lambda x:x[1], reverse=True) #sort by value
    print("Sorted by Value Descending",[i for i, _ in sorted_list[:10]]) # [:10] for slicing 10 sorted values

# calling the function
my_list = [('abc',10),('def',15),('ghi',10),('abc', 12),('xyz',100)]
ranked_games(my_list)
print('Original List: ', my_list)
```

Result:

```
Sorted by Value Descending ['xyz', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'ghi']
Original List:  [('abc', 10), ('def', 15), ('ghi', 10), ('abc', 12), ('xyz', 100)]
```

For more about difference between `sort` and `sorted`, you can look at relevant question [What is the difference between `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the combining part. The 'abc' must be combined before the sorting can be done, otherwise you are not really sorting the right list:

```
l = [('abc', 10), ('def', 15), ('ghi', 10), ('abc', 12), ('xyz', 100)]
diction = {}
for (i, j) in l:
    if i in diction:
        diction[i] = diction[i] + j
    else:
        diction[i] = j
sorted_list = list(diction.items())
sorted_list = sorted(sorted_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

print(sorted_list[:10])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[('abc',10),('def',15),('ghi',10),('abc', 12),('xyz',100)]

sortedlist = sorted(l,key = lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
d=dict(sortedlist)

print(list(d.keys()))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.