# Function to iterate through multi level list nested with dicts does not work properly

Tags: python

I want to compare two lists and verify if they are the same. Though the lists might have items in a different order so just comparing `list1 == list2` would not work.
Those lists can be nested into multi-level with dicts, strings, integers, and lists, so just using `sorted(list1) == sorted(list2)` would not work either.

I'm trying to create a function that iterates through a multi-level list and sort each list inside of it in ascending order.
The results I'm having so far only sorts the first level `main` list. All the other "sub lists" get sorted inside the function but when I print the final result they are unsorted the same way before using the function.

Function created so far:

```
def sort_multilevel_obj(items):    
    if isinstance(items, dict):
        for v in items.values():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                v = sorted(v)
            v = sort_multilevel_obj(v)
    if isinstance(items, list):
        items = sorted(items)
        for i in items:
            i = sort_multilevel_obj(i)

    return items
```

Example of multi-level list:

```
mylist = [
    'string1',
    [
        {
            1:'one',
            2:'two',
            3:[4,2,'ddd'],
            4:{'x':'xx'}
        },
        'substring'
    ],
    {
        'somekey':7,
        'anotherkey':[
            'ccccccc',
            100,
            4,
            'blabla'
        ]
    }
]
```

When I pass the list into the function the result I got is:

```
[{'z': ['ccccccc', 100, 4, 'afsafas'], 'f': 7}, [{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: [4, 2, 'ddd'], 4: {'x': 'xx'}}, 'substring'], 'string1']
```

The fist list (string, list, dict) is sorted properly (to dict, list, string) but the list inside the dict (`['ccccccc', 100, 4, 'afsafas']`) should be returned as `[4, 100, 'afsafas', 'ccccccc']` but this just doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're creating `i` & `v` but not using them anywhere.

Comment: Which exactly python version are you using? I tried run the code and caught this exception: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `v.sort()` instead of `v = sorted(v)`. `v.sort()` mutates the original list while `sorted(v)` returns a new object. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22442440/3486675) for another explanation about the difference between `v.sort()` and `sorted(v)`.

The reason why `v = sorted(v)` doesn't change the value in the list/dict itself is because the variable `v` is basically only a reference to the original value in the dict/list. When you use `v = <something>` you're pointing that variable to another object and thus not changing the original value.