# Python - sorted() vs sort()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

```
    Python 3.6.7

    >>> a = [('a',1), ('b', 2), ('c',3), ('d',4)]
    >>> b = [('b',2), ('c', 3), ('a',1)]
    >>>
    >>>
    >>> a.sort() == b.sort()
    True

    >>> a = [('a',1), ('b', 2), ('c',3), ('d',4)]
    >>> b = [('b',2), ('c', 3), ('a',1)]
    >>>
    >>> sorted(a) == sorted(b)
    False
    >>>
```

I was expecting sort() to return false. What is the difference between sort and sorted causing this behaviour.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22442440/11793921 I think this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: `a.sort() == b.sort()` compares `None == None`

Comment: `sort()` return None
But
`sorted()` return sorted list.