# Anything faster than `sorted()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'd like to sort a list with a custom `cmp`. The original list can be destroyed. But `sorted()` will return a list. I assume that it involves copying. Each element in the original list is not a small object, I want avoid copying and reuse as much the original list as possible.

Is there something like this available in python?

Comment: You can use `list.sort`, which sorts in-place. However, the size of the individual elements of the original list won't matter, as Python will just copy references, not contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`sorted(list)\` vs \`list.sort()\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort)

Comment: The elements aren't copied, only a new list

Comment: @L3viathan Did you mean `sorted()` only copy references but the contents?

Comment: @user1424739 Yes, that's how assignment works in general, in Python.