# Is this call chaining legal in python?

Tags: python, syntax

I am perplexed at the behavior of python code below. 
I want to sort last 3 numbers in a list. But when I chain the operations, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Behavior 1:

```
>>> a = [10,4,2,3]
>>> b = a[1:].sort() # I want to sort last 3 numbers. But when I chain the 
                     # operations, it doesn't work. Why?
>>> b
<empty value>
```

====

Behavior 2:

```
>>> a = [10,4,2,3]
>>> b = a[1:]
>>> b.sort()
>>> b
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It is _legal_ but it's useless. `.sort()` works _in place_ and returns `None` so it's useless in an assignment. `b = ...` in `b = a[1:].sort()` is an assignment, so you get `None` back. Look into `sorted()`

Comment: Instead, you can do `b = sorted(a[1:])`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22442440/11981207

Comment: I agree. But if I execute  a[1:].sort() then this does not sort "a" which is how the whole investigation started.

Answer (score 2):

This is because .sort() does not return a new list but rather mutates the existing list. E.g. `[5, 2, 7, 4, 5].sort()` does not return anything.
Take a look at this:

```
a = [2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 6]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

The output is:

```
[2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7]
```

What you might want to do is this:

```
a = [2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 6]
b = sorted(a[1:])
print(a)
print(b)
```