# Modify on the list in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

the purpose of the code is to merge nums2 into nums1 as one sorted array.
the first approach doesn't work as expected, the second one works fine, any explanation?

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        nums1 = sorted(nums1[:m]+nums2[:n])

class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        nums1[m:]=nums2
        nums1.sort()
```

Comment: Can you explain better what do you mean by 'return', currently both functions are returning nothing.

Comment: In the second example the variable is not modified but the list it refers to.

Comment: Did you check the docs? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: @HoxhaAlban please check again the question

Comment: @MichaelButscher could you please explain more with en example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, `sorted` creates a *new* list that only lives for the duration of the function body.  The `nums1` label that you give to that new list effectively [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the input parameter named `nums1`.

In the second example, you modify `nums1` in-place, which affects the calling object.  You never create any new variables, you are only working with memory that is external to the function.

Generally the first solution is preferred (assuming you modify it to `return` the modified list) because it is very clear at the call site that the function will modify the list that was passed in.  The second solution should only be used under rare circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` change the list *in-place*, while `sorted()` builds a new sorted list

eg:

```
l = [3, 4, 1]
a = sorted(l)
print(a, l)
out: [1, 3, 4] [3, 4, 1] # l does not change

b = l.sort()
print(b, l)
out: None [1, 3, 4] # l changes and b is None because list().sort returns None
```

The official python docs are probably the best docs you can find to learn python, check this: [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

also: [What is the difference between `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort)

Comment: Thank you @Hoxha Alban, I already knew the difference between sorted() and sort() what I missed is the shadowing definition. appreciated your efforts bro