# Sort a Python List of Dictionaries with TimeStamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, timestamp

Here is a simplifed version of a list of dictionaries I from the MailChimp api and I'm using the function to get a sorted list based on timestamp_out.  When I run this I get 'none' as the output.  It seems this should work.  Does anybody know what is going on and how to make it simply output a sorted list?  Thanks - and yes, I've searched for this but haven't an answer yet.

```
 memberList=[{'email_address': 'aaa@gmail.com', 'timestamp_opt': '2020-07-17T00:49:53+00:00'}, {'email_address': 'bbb@yahoo.com', 'timestamp_opt': '2020-07-17T01:29:47+00:00'}]

  def key_function(item_dictionary):
     datetime_string = item_dictionary['timestamp_opt']
     return datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')


 sortList=memberList.sort(key=key_function)

 print(sortList)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
sortList = memberList.sort(key=key_function)
```

to this:

```
sortList = sorted(memberList, key=key_function)
```

`sort` changes the original `memberList` in-place, and doesn't return anything, which is why you get the `None` you're seeing. However, `sorted` returns a new list, which we can assign to `sortList`.

See [What is the difference between `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort) for further details.

Comment: Thanks Mario...I really appreciate this.