# Problem in sorting a list converted from tuple

Tags: python, list, sorting, set

I am writing a program to take a list of words from the user, remove the repeated words and then print the output after sorting the words. However, I ran into this issue while sorting:

```
a = set(input('Words: ').split(' '))
b = list(a).sort()

print(b)
```

The terminal prints 'None' as the result of the code, but in this case:

```
a = set(input('Words: ').split(' '))
b = list(a)
b.sort()
print(b)
```

It gives the right output. Why is this so?

Comment: The `sort()` function sorts the list inplace it doesn't return anything. So in the first case, b would contain `None`. However you could use the `sorted()` function to correct the first code.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between item.sort() and sorted(item) is explained (when to use which) in detail here  : [What is the difference between `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort)