# Sum dictionary values, using two keys as index: how to achieve this?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing, key

I have the following dictionary:

```
res = [{'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0}, 
{'name': 'serv', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0}, 
{'name': 'inv', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1200.0, 'tax_amount': 168.0}, 
{'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 50.0, 'tax_base': 1500.0, 'tax_amount': 210.0}, 
{'name': 'none', 'percentage': 0.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 0.0}, 
{'name': 'none', 'percentage': 0.0, 'tax_base': 900.0, 'tax_amount': 126.0}, 
{'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 50.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0}]
```

From this dictionary, I need to sum 'tax_base' and 'tax_amount' value keys, and use keys 'name' and 'percentage' as index.

As a result, I need:

```
res_final = [{'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0},
{'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 50.0, 'tax_base': 2500.0, 'tax_amount': 350.0},  
{'name': 'serv', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0}, 
{'name': 'inv', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1200.0, 'tax_amount': 168.0}, 
{'name': 'none', 'percentage': 0.0, 'tax_base': 1900.0, 'tax_amount': 126.0}, 
]
```

How can I achieve this? Can you provide me a sample please?

Comment: Loop over the dictionaries,  and create a new dictionary with the keys `name` and `percentage` (can be a tuple), and the values a dictionary with the `tax_base` and `tax_amount`,  if they entry exists, add the values. Then as last you can iterate again over the dictionary to return it to the form you want. The above is an example, I suppose there are many more (and probably some better) approaches.

Comment: As I look at this a bit longer, you can also make it a [pd.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function with aggregation. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for an example.

Comment: @Thymen, can you please send me a sample of the first approach please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your original input, `res` and your preferred output `res_final`, the following code would work:

```
# Creating a temporary dictionary with the aggregation
temp_result = {}
for each in res:
    key = (each['name'], each['percentage'])
    if key not in temp_result:
        temp_result[key] = dict(tax_base=0, tax_amount=0)

    temp_result[key]['tax_base'] += each['tax_base']
    temp_result[key]['tax_amount'] += each['tax_amount']

# Transforming the temporary dictionary to the correct format
final_result = []
for (name, percentage), taxes in temp_result.items():
    final_result.append(dict(
            name=name,
            percentage=percentage,
            tax_base=taxes['tax_base'],
            tax_amount=taxes['tax_amount']
    ))

for each in final_result:
    print(each)
```

The result will be:

```
{'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0}
{'name': 'serv', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0}
{'name': 'inv', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1200.0, 'tax_amount': 168.0}
{'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 50.0, 'tax_base': 2500.0, 'tax_amount': 350.0}
{'name': 'none', 'percentage': 0.0, 'tax_base': 1900.0, 'tax_amount': 126.0}
```

#### Explanation

In the first part we create a new dictionary, that has as key the combination of `name` and `percentage` as a `tuple`, and as value a dictionary with the `tax_base` and `tax_amount` for that key.

Then we check if the key is already in our dictionary and if it isn't we create the key. The final step is summing the `tax_base` and `tax_amount`.

Now we have one dictionary with all the information, but not in the right format. The second part takes care of that. We split the key again into the `name` and `percentage` and merge the data with `tax_base` and `tax_amount` to one dict.

---

### Edit

In case people are wondering how to do it with `pd.DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
res = df.groupby(['name', 'percentage'], as_index=False).sum()
final_result = res.to_dict('records')

for each in final_result:
    print(each)
```

Will result in the same output, but it is not guaranteed to be in the same order as the input.

Comment: Dear @Thymen, this is working as expected. Since the order is not important it is exactly what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's another (very similar) way of doing it but a little bit more concise.

Here we first create a list of unique `name:percentage` pairs and then loop over those unique keys, filtering out entries from the `res` list that do not match that unique key.

```
unique_keys = list(set([f"{d['name']}:{d['percentage']}" for d in res])) # use list(set()) to keep only unique values as keys
output = []

for key in unique_keys:
    name, percentage = key.split(":")
    matching_entries = list(filter(lambda d: d['name'] == name and str(d['percentage']) == percentage, res))
    
    summed = {"name": name, "percentage": float(percentage), "tax_base": 0.0, "tax_amount": 0.0}
    for entry in matching_entries:
        summed["tax_base"] += entry.get("tax_base", 0) # use get in case value is not in dictionary, 0 is default value
        summed["tax_amount"] += entry.get("tax_amount", 0)
    
    output.append(summed)

output.sort(key=lambda d: d['name']) # sorting to organize a bit
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'inv', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1200.0, 'tax_amount': 168.0},
 {'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0},
 {'name': 'mfi', 'percentage': 50.0, 'tax_base': 2500.0, 'tax_amount': 350.0},
 {'name': 'none', 'percentage': 0.0, 'tax_base': 1900.0, 'tax_amount': 126.0},
 {'name': 'serv', 'percentage': 100.0, 'tax_base': 1000.0, 'tax_amount': 140.0}]
```

Comment: Hi @djvaroli, perhaps I missed something here. It's returning None when trying to print output.sort. The answer from Thymen solved my issue but anyway, I wanted to test your approach in order to understand it also

Comment: @pmatos, the reason you get `None` is because `output.sort()` is an `in-place`  modification, it changes the list, but doesn't return a new list. You can print his output by printing `output` (the variable). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort) post for a more elaborate answer.