# How do I add values (list) of a list of dictionaries if their key is same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have got a list of dictionaries,

```py
_list = [
    {"a": [1, 20, 20, 40], "b": [0, 14, 14, 28]},
    {"a": [2, 20, 20, 40], "b": [2, 14, 14, 28]},
    {"c": [1, 20, 20, 40], "d": [0, 14, 14, 28]},
]
```

I want to merge these dict and get a single dict, I want their values which are lists to be merged if the key is same and I expect the final result like this:

```py
_dict = {
    "a": [3, 40, 40, 80], 
    "b": [2, 28, 28, 56], 
    "c": [1, 20, 20, 40], 
    "d": [0, 14, 14, 28]
    }
```

I have no idea where to start and what approach to follow, can you please help me to get the desired output?
Thanks

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411153/sum-dictionary-values-using-two-keys-as-index-how-to-achieve-this/66412584#66412584. Would that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic solution, no the most efficient but works:

```
_list = [
  {"a": [1, 20, 20, 40], "b": [0, 14, 14, 28]},
  {"a": [2, 20, 20, 40], "b": [2, 14, 14, 28]},
  {"c": [1, 20, 20, 40], "d": [0, 14, 14, 28]},
]


_dict = {}

for dict_item in _list:
  for key, value in dict_item.items():
    if key in _dict:
      val = [a + b for a, b in zip(_dict[key], value)]
      _dict[key] = val
    else:
      _dict[key] = value

print(_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

m=[{k:np.array(v) for k,v in i.items()} for i in _list]
df=pd.DataFrame(m)
df=df.fillna(0)
_dict = {i:list(sum(df[i])) for i in df.columns}

print(_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [3, 40, 40, 80], 'b': [2, 28, 28, 56], 'c': [1, 20, 20, 40], 'd': [0, 14, 14, 28]}
```