# How do i change Numbers i sorted into Words

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, variables

I want to sort a list, wich I do with the .sort or sorted command.
Afterwards i want to change the Numbers into words so it makes more sense to read.

My Problem:

```
Calculation1 = 0+1   #because i need to cacluate something first
calculation2 = 1+1

list1 = [1, 2]

list1.sort()
```

output:
2, 1

but I want to change 2, 1 so it says FirstInvestment, SecondInvestment

thx for the help and constructive criticism

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \`sorted(list)\` vs \`list.sort()\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort)

Comment: What are you *really* trying to achieve? [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Do you want to sort by the text names or the values?

Comment: I want to sort by the Values

Comment: "but how do i change the variable without making a new list and assign the variables t1 and t2 new like:" Why does it matter? Why not just `List1 = sorted(List1)`? in any case, you can always use the `.sort` method on `list` objects if you want to sort them in-place

Comment: "because if i do it like this i would "unsort" the whole thing" What???

Comment: @MrrLIme Ah, I see. You are fundamentally confused, *variables are not strings*. Objects have no idea what variables might refer to them, and in general, **should never need to care**. If you want numbers associated with strings, then you need to create a data structure that does that (a dict, a list of tuples, etc). Fundamentally, you need to understand that *variables are for source code*, their names shouldn't contain program data.

Comment: The reason your description is confusing is because `[big, small] ` **doesn't have any text**. `big` and `small` are *variables* But note, list objects, or any other object, *don't contain or refer to variables*. They contain or refer to *other objects*. Again, *variables are for source code*. Their for the *human reading the code*.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a method that returns a new list. So what's happening is you call `sorted()` on `List1` and sorted is returning a new list for you (which you don't use). Then you print out the original list.

You should use the in-place sort on the list object.

```
List1 = [t1, t2]
List1.sort()
print(List1)
```

Comment: The Problem is mainly that i dont get a text as output( wich is my goal) but a number that i wanna change into a text. but still thx for your effort

Comment: @MrrLIme you are not making *any* sense