# How to order a list alphabetically in python/mako

Tags: python, alphabetical, mako

so I have this (very stupid for most people I'd assume) question: I'm trying to modify a small template I found online and at one point they give the order to sort the list called `movie` by rating in descending order via this command:
`recently_added['movie'].sort(key=lambda m: m['rating'], reverse=True)`

I'd like to sort this list alphabetically A to Z myself, but for the life of me can't figure out how to do it! Is it possible? I think I should be using .sorted() instead of .sort() but I'm not sure.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to just remove `key=lambda m: m['rating'], reverse=True` I asssume. The key in the example denotes which value to use when comparing. In the example it's the rating of the movie, but you just want the name of the movie which is the default key(since those are the values of the list). The `reversed=True` just denotes wether to use `< or >`.

then onto the differences between sort and sorted see [What is the difference between `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort). ;TLDR `sorted` creates a copy, `.sort()` manipulates the original list.

Answer (score 1):

The list.sort() sorts alphabetically by default.

```
data = ['Elle', 'Miles', 'Kratos', 'Joel', 'Peter', 'Nathan']

data.sort()
print(data)

Output
['Elle', 'Joel', 'Kratos', 'Miles', 'Nathan', 'Peter']
```

A quick google search provided the reference https://appdividend.com/2021/06/02/how-to-sort-list-alphabetically-in-python/