# Why is the new list still the same as the old list after sorting?

Tags: python

```
l=[3,2,1]
x=l
x.sort()
x==l
True
```

The above occurrence happens in Python. I am confused since after applying sort on `x`, `x` should become the list `[1,2,3`] which is different from `[3,2,1]`.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort) can help you understand

Comment: `x` does become what you expect, the problem is that `l` does too.

Comment: @Passerby Why does it modify l? Since x was only initially defined as equal to l, but the sorting was only done on x.

Comment: The issue is not with `.sort`, but with `x=l`, which _doesn't create a different list_ as you expect. Instead, `x` and `l` are references to the same list.

Comment: *x* is merely a reference to *l*. Try *x=l.copy()* or *x=l[::]* That may help you to understand what's going on

Comment: Who told you people that something like `x=l` makes a copy? Seriously, I want to know. I'm always wondering why people think that.

Answer (score 0):

When you create `x` and assign it to `l`, you are not creating a new list. When you do that, you're making `l` point to the value of `x`. This is different when you do this with integers, for example, where

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
print(b)
```

outputs 1.

Try printing `x` and `l` separately to check this. `x` has a value of `[1, 2, 3]`, and so does `l`.