# Order of Operations - Tuples, Lambda, Sort, Print

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda, tuples

Might be a silly question but taking a course we just talked about lambda and how it can be used. One of our exercises was to sort a list based on second number in tuples. Example list:

```
a = [(0, 2), (4, 3), (9, 9), (10, -1)]
```

Sort based on the numbers 2, 3, 9, and -1 for an expected result of:

```
[(10, -1), (0, 2), (4, 3), (9, 9)]
```

My code was the following:

```
print(a.sort(key=lambda num: num[1]))
```

The correct answer is:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
print(a)
```

Seeing how I essentially had the same answer, this leads me to think I had the order of operations incorrect somewhere. The output of my code was "None" and the output of the correct answer is the expected result above.

What am I missing here? Is there another way to do it correctly?

Comment: So when you wrote your code, how did you know whether it worked or not?

Comment: `list.sort` is in place, so `a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` returns nothing, and `print(a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]))` would incorrectly display `None`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \`sorted(list)\` vs \`list.sort()\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort)

Comment: @mozway how can I get it to return the sorted list within print() or is it required to do the sort and then print the sorted list?

Comment: So if I understand right, a.sort() performs an operation on the list a but having a.sort() within the print() does not return anything because it is performing the operation of sort on list a hence why says "None"? And to get the sorted list after the operation has been performed we do print(a) to get the sorted list?

Comment: Did you follow the link provided by cafce25?

Comment: @parrtakenn use `print(sorted(a, key=lambda num: num[1]))`

Comment: Thank you all, very helpful in understanding the topic.