# Python how to cast tuple to list and apply dot notation

Tags: python

Why does:

```
x = (5,4,3)
y = list(x)
y.sort()
```

work, but

```
x = (5,4,3)
y = list(x).sort()
```

not work?

Comment: Because `sort` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You wanted `y = sorted(x)`. Refer to the docs for [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) and [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), and perhaps the [How To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto).

Comment: Do you notice that that first code example does not use the return value from `sort()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y = list(x)
```

this calls the function `list` on `x` and puts the result in y

```
y = list(x).sort()
```

this calls the function `list` on `x`, call `.sort()` on the resulting list, then store **the return of .sort()** in `y`, the return of `.sort()` is `None`.

the list is sorted in memory but the sorted list is thrown away, and only `None` is stored in `y`.

---

relevent [What is the difference between sort and sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort)

Answer (score 2):

The `sort()` method in **Python** sorts the elements of a list in-place and returns `None`.

When you do something like:

```
y = list(x).sort()
```

You can, using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) containing the sorted elements of the tuple x.

```
y = sorted(x)
```

---

> If you want to create a new sorted list without modifying the original, you should use the `sorted()` function

Answer (score 0):

In the second scenario, using only
`list(x).sort()`
instead of
`y = list(x).sort()`
should work since you cannot "stock" the results of the sort method.

Comment: Hmmm, is "stock" a verb that shows up somewhere in the python.org documentation? Not sure how it fits into this context.